# Python reading from a file and saving to utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

I'm having problems reading from a file, processing its string and saving to an UTF-8 File.

Here is the code:

```
try:
    filehandle = open(filename,"r")
except:
    print("Could not open file " + filename)
    quit() 

text = filehandle.read()
filehandle.close()
```

I then do some processing on the variable text.

And then

```
try:
    writer = open(output,"w")
except:
    print("Could not open file " + output)
    quit() 

#data = text.decode("iso 8859-15")    
#writer.write(data.encode("UTF-8"))
writer.write(text)
writer.close()
```

This output the file perfectly but it does so in iso 8859-15 according to my editor. Since the same editor recognizes the input file (in the variable filename) as UTF-8 I don't know why this happened. As far as my reasearch has shown the commented lines should solve the problem. However when I use those lines the resulting file has gibberish in special character mainly, words with tilde as the text is in spanish. I would really appreciate any help as I am stumped....

Comment: Which editor is this? Which python version? From here this code seems to be completely valid and should work as expected …

Comment: Kate is the editor. The output of python --version is Python 2.7.5+

Comment: I've tested your code with 2.6.8, 2.7.5+ and 3.3.2+ everything works fine. Could you provide some example input?

Comment: Since the text was processed in raw bytes the unseen processing code probably messed up the UTF8 encoding.

Comment: I'd love to provide an example file however I can't find a way to uploaded it here...

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have commented all my unseen code however the error remains. It was a good idea though...

Comment: Ok. I've solved it. It was mostly my fault so sorry everyone. Here is what happened. The code provided by @MarkTolonen worked if I change iso-8859-15 instead of utf-8 when opening the file. However as my editor updated the file from memory having already loaded the old encoding it showed me the gibberish. When I opened the file again it showed it to me fine. Thank you all and sorry for the bother!!!

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Process text to and from Unicode at the I/O boundaries of your program using `open` with the `encoding` parameter.  Make sure to use the (hopefully documented) encoding of the file being read.  The default encoding varies by OS (specifically, `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is the encoding used), so I recommend always explicitly using the `encoding` parameter for portability and clarity (Python 3 syntax below):

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# process Unicode text

with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

If still using Python 2 or for Python 2/3 compatibility, the `io` module implements `open` with the same semantics as Python 3's `open` and exists in both versions:

```
import io
with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()

# process Unicode text

with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: I did exactly what you told me. Same error as with the other suggestion

Comment: I've got it to work. Problem was the original file was iso-8859-15

Comment: @aarelovich you may need to pass `errors=ignore` or `errors=replace` to `open()` ... if you do not know the file's encoding. :)

Comment: Doesn't work with the string "présenté alloué ééé ààà tué"

Comment: @LiorMagen I assume you are the recent down voter. You do have to write the string in a file and specify the encoding used, which may not be UTF8.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! Saved me when converted my colleague's old DOS file in ibm852 to utf8.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I guess it would be unnecessarily redundant to write `f.write(text.encode('utf-8'))` given the `encoding='utf8'` parameter in `io.open()`, right?

Comment: @arturomp It also wouldn't work.  `io.open` expects Unicode strings to be written, not byte strings.  It does the encoding to the declared encoding.

Comment: @arturomp Correction, it won't work on Python 3.  Python 2 will implicitly convert the byte string back to Unicode using the default `ascii` codec, so it will work as long as the string is only ASCII.  That's why Python 3 changed it...it prevents "it will work sometimes" which is an annoying bug to track down.

Answer (score 13):

You can also get through it by the code below:

```
file=open(completefilepath,'r',encoding='utf8',errors="ignore")
file.read()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that using open. use codecs.

when you are opening a file in python using the open built-in function you will always read/write the file in ascii. To write it in utf-8 try this:

```
import codecs
file = codecs.open('data.txt','w','utf-8')
```

Comment: Tried this and I got an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 57: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Are you saving with the utf-8 encode? look, if you`re reading from another file that is ascii, you have to decode it first.

Comment: The code is as you see it. What I did is replaced the line writer = open(output,'w') with writer = codecs.open(output,'w','utf-8') and that got me that error

Answer (score 1):

The encoding parameter is what does the trick.

```
my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
    for i in my_list:
        file.write(i + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using utf-16, it might work.

```
data = pd.read_table(filename, encoding='utf-16', delimiter="\t")
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of @Fernando and @Silva solutions is the best for me:

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as f:
    text = f.read()
```