# Problems with the encoding of several concatenated files in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I have a folder of lots of `.txt` files in spanish and I decided to merge them in one `.txt` file as follows:

import os
import shutil

```
def concatFiles():
    path = '/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt/'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    with open("/Users/user/Desktop/concat_file.txt", "wb") as fo:
        for f in files:
            with open(os.path.join(path, f), "rb") as fi:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fi, fo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    concatFiles()
```

The problem is that the output(i.e. `concat_file`) doesn't respect the character spanish encoding for example in the `concat_file` is `direcci√≥n` instead of `dirección`. Another thing is that I'm working in OS X, when i open the `concat_file` with sublime text it looks like this: `0000 0001 2000 0000 0000 0001 4000 0000` and when i open `concat_file` with text edit it looks as i wanted, why is this happenning and how can i solve it?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using codecs, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591815/4339369. This will allow you to read and write the files as UTF-8, which may solve your problem.

```
import codecs
import os
import shutil
def concatFiles():
    path = '/Users/user/Desktop/OpinionsTAG_txt/'
    files = os.listdir(path)
    with codecs.open("/Users/user/Desktop/concat_file.txt", "wb",encoding='utf8') as fo:
        for f in files:
            with codecs.open(os.path.join(path, f), "rb",encoding='utf8') as fi:
                shutil.copyfileobj(fi, fo)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    concatFiles()
```

A good overview of Unicode issues in Python 2.x can be found here: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html.

Edit for anyone in the future: on OS X, you can usually determine a file's encoding by

```
file -I <filename>
```

from [How do I determine file encoding in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539294/how-do-i-determine-file-encoding-in-osx).

Comment: Thanks, this is the output:`newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 10: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: Does this means that the files are not in utf8?

Comment: It's a bit of a guess-and-check if you don't already know how the files are encoded.

Comment: i tried with utf8, utf16, utf32 and ascii. Still get the same exception. What else can i do?

Comment: See the terminal command that I edited in at the end of my post. It should be able to tell you how the Spanish files are encoded.

Comment: Still have the same problem, when i look at the terminal for info about the .txt files it says the spanish texts are encoded as `utf-8`. This is the trace error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 10: invalid continuation byte

Comment: That worked but now instead of direcci√≥n now i have direcciÃ³n. The correct should be dirección. What other type of encoding should i try?

Comment: cp1252 or mac_roman or utf-7 are possibilities I guess. I'm running out of ideas.