# Python add Unicode characters at the start of a file

Tags: c#, python, unicode, encoding, ironpython

I use a script to update the version of each AssemblyVersion.cs file of a .NET project. It always worked perfectly, but since a format my PC, it adds unicode character at the start of each .cs file edited. Like this:

```
ï»¿Ã¯Â»Â¿using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
```

I use this code to open a file:

```
with open(fname,  "r") as f:
    out_fname = fname + ".tmp"
    out = codecs.open(out_fname, "w", encoding='utf-8')
    textInFile=""
    for line in f:
        textInFile += (re.sub(pat, s_after,line))
    out.write(u'\uFEFF')
    out.write(textInFile)
    out.close()
os.remove(fname)
os.rename(out_fname, fname)
```

I've also tried, as wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591458/python-reading-from-a-file-and-saving-to-utf-8), to use `io` instead of `codecs`, but nothing is changed.

On other teammates' PCs it works with the same configuration (Win10 and IronPython 2.7).

What can I try to solve this issue? Where can I looking for the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the files at your file system are using ISO-8859-1 encoding, while you are adding the UT8 BOM marker at the beginning of each file.

After your code does it's job, you get a file with UTF-8 BOM + ISO-8859-1 meta at the beginning.

I would check the encoding of your input files before modification with Notepad++ (or any other editor) just to see if the scenario I described is valid. If it is, you will need to read your input files with a different encoding in order to avoid the metadata:

```
with open(fname,  "r",  "ISO-8859-1") as f:
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm late. However, the encoding of files processed is UTF-8 BOM (in the specific, these files are the AssemblyInfo.cs of a .NET project). I've also tried to add "ISO-8859-1" as you indicated, in read and write methods too, but it doesn't work.

Comment: If the files you are processing are UTF-8 BOM then you should use 'utf-8-sig' encoding not the regular 'utf-8'. Maybe that is the issue, as you are reading it like a regular UTF-8 file the BOM marker gets read and appended at the beginning of a file that already has a BOM that you wrote manually.

Comment: I've tried in this way but it still doesn't work
`with codecs.open(fname,  "r") as f:
out_fname = fname + ".tmp"
out = codecs.open(out_fname, "w", encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Any other suggestion?

Comment: with codecs.open(fname, "r", "utf-8-sig") as f:  I believe that the source file is the main cause, and that opening it in the correct format is necessary.