# How can I implement a file like class that always returns in UTF-8 encoding irrespective of file encoding?

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8

I have made a module that detects the encoding of a file. I want to be able to able to give file path and encoding as inputs to the class and always be able to get back 'utf-8' when I process the contents of the file.

For example something like this

```
handler = UnicodeWrapper(file_path, encoding='ISO-8859-2')

for line in handler:
   # need the line to be encoded in utf-8
   process(line)
```

I can not understand why there are a million types of encodings yet. But I want to write an interface that always returns unicode.

Is there a library to do this already?

Comment: Not exactly, but the `Codecs` module gives you wrappers that allow you to read a file into unicode strings, more or less what Python3 open also directly allows.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591815/1636276), I think the following might suit your needs:

```
import io

class UnicodeWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename

    def __iter__(self):
        with io.open(self._filename,'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            return iter(f.readlines())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = r'...'

    handler = UnicodeWrapper(filename)

    for line in handler:
       print(line)
```

**Edit**

In Python 2, you can assert that each line is encoded in UTF-8 using something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = r'...'

    handler = UnicodeWrapper(filename)

    for line in handler:
        try:
            line.decode('utf-8')
            # process(line)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print('Not encoded in UTF-8')
```