# convert ansi escape to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, richtext

I may be wrong in accessing weather this string is ansi or anything else but it comes from rtf docs with heading.

`{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252`

the string of interest from doc is:

```
ansi_string = r'3 \u176? \u177? 0.2\u176? (2\u952?)'
```

when i open the doc with word it gives me : **3° ± 0.2° 2θ**

**Questions are:**
1) what are these escape codes?
is it possible to convert this string to utf-8 using python inbuilt methods?

Comment: are you reading the content from some file!?

Comment: Yes. .rtf file...

Comment: See if this helps! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591458/python-reading-from-a-file-and-saving-to-utf-8

Comment: The encoding of the .rtf is already utf-8. The string inside is ansi escaped. I just want to convert to corresponding utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is the best answer but to make a point what I want, here is the working code.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System")
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
import System.Windows.Forms as WinForms

def rtf_to_text(rtf_str):
    rtf = r"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252" + '\n' + rtf_str + '\n' + '}'
    richTextBox = WinForms.RichTextBox()
    richTextBox.Rtf = rtf
    return richTextBox.Text

print(rtf_to_text(r'3 \u176? \u177? 0.2\u176? (2\u952?)'))
-->'3 ° ± 0.2° (2θ)'
```