# Python repr string w/ real newlines

Tags: python, string, repr

I want to use `repr()` to get a Python-encoded string literal (that I can paste into some source code), but I'd prefer a triple-quoted string with real newlines rather than the `\n` escape sequence.

I could post-process the string to convert `\n` back into a newline char and add a couple more quotes, but then if `\\n` is in the source, then I wouldn't want to match on that.

What's the easiest way to do this?

---

Example input:

```
foo
bar
```

Or as a Python string:

```
'foo\nbar'
```

Desired output:

```
'''foo\xf0\x9f\x92\xa9
bar'''
```

Triple-single or triple-double quotes is fine, but I do want it broken on multiple lines like that.

---

What I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r+') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    out = "''" + re.sub(r"\\n", '\n', repr(data)) + "''"
    f.write(out)
    f.truncate()
```

I'm still trying to figure out the regex to avoid converting escaped `\n`s.

The goal is that if I paste that back into a Python source file I will get back out exactly the same thing as I read in.

---

I'm using Python 2.7.14

Comment: Isn't that just `print(your_string)`?  I don't really get your desired input and output.

Comment: @wim No. `repr` will escape quotes, emojis and other control characters, which I do want.

Comment: OK, please post an example input and output.  Btw repr will not escape emojis in the current version of Python - maybe you should tag this with python-2.x ?

Comment: @wim Added to question.

Comment: Are you really sure you want `'foo\nbar'` and not `u'foo\nbar'`?   The proper escape here would be `foo\U0001f4a9\nbar` - what you are showing here is utf-8 encoded

Comment: Uhh.. yeah, I think you're right. I don't actually have any emoji poops in my source, but there might be some other wonky stuff. I basically just need Python to be able to parse it and come out the same way as the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `splitlines` it and encoding each line separately:

```
s = 'foo\nbar'

r = "'''" + '\n'.join(repr(x)[1:-1] for x in s.splitlines()) + "'''"

assert eval(r) == s
```

If you're on python2 and the inputs are unicode, then `repr[2:-1]` to strip the leading `u` as well. The same applies to py3 and bytes inputs.

Comment: Smart. Split the lines before calling `repr` to avoid the whole escaping issue.

Answer (score 0):

Final solution to convert a text file into a string which you can paste into your source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import re
import io

with io.open(sys.argv[1], 'r+', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    out = u"u'''" + u'\n'.join(repr(x)[2:-1] for x in data.splitlines()) + u"'''"
    f.write(out)
    f.truncate()
```

Warning: it overwrites the source file. I'm using temporary files for this, so that's what I wanted.

Credit:

- [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55408161/65387)
- [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591815/65387)