# how to read bson files with utf-8 encoding?

Tags: python, bson

I want to read a `bson` file with `utf-8` encoding but I don't know where to insert the encoding format.

here is my code:

```
with open('filename.bson','rb') as f:
    data = bson.decode_all(f.read())
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591815/2681662

Answer (score 0):

You can insert encoding within `open` function

```
with open('filename.bson','rb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = bson.decode_all(f.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import io

f = io.open('filename.bson', mode='rb', encoding='utf-8')
```